# Как сделать некоторые пункты QComboBox временно недоступными для выбора

Tags: c++, qt5, qcombobox

коллеги!
Среда IDE QT Creator 5.10. У меня такой вопрос. Есть QComboBox, у которого много пунктов. В зависимости от смены режимов некоторые пункты должны становиться недоступными для выбора, но нельзя просто стереть текущий набор пунктов и заполнить только разрешёнными. Надо сделать чтобы недоступные пункты остались, но изменили цвет на серый и стали недоступными для выбора пользователем. Необходимо чтобы номера разрешённых пунктов выпадающего меню не изменялись потому что выбор пунктов и смену режимов может выполнять не только пользователь, но и управляемая система, а у неё номера фиксированные.
Пример:

```
QStringList interlivingPSK;
interlivingPSK << "1: Zero"
               << "2: Ultra Short"
               << "3: Very Short"
               << "4: Short"
               << "5: Medium"
               << "6: Long"
               << "7: Very Long";
ui->comboBoxInterleaverPSK->addItems(interlivingPSK);
ui->comboBoxInterleaverPSK->setCurrentIndex(4);
```

Как, например, "загрэить" пункты 2, 3, 5, 7 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Обратитесь к модели `QComboBox` и через нее сделайте элементы неактивными:

```
QStandardItemModel* model = (QStandardItemModel*) ui->comboBoxInterleaverPSK->model();
model->item(1)->setEnabled(false);
model->item(2)->setEnabled(false);
model->item(4)->setEnabled(false);
model->item(6)->setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает! Только зачем Ложь с большой буквы?

Comment: @Виктор, нажимая на галочку (приняв ответ) вы выразите благодарность, и что ответ решил ваши проблемы

Comment: @Виктор, код переписывал [из кода на питоне](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/f3bb5cf67f224f07b3f3539f78414929bf2044db/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/disable_specific_items_in_QComboBox.py#L21) и не заметил False :)