# Как сделать некоторые пункты QComboBox временно недоступными для выбора в PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qcombobox, qstandarditemmodel

Мне нужно отключить **`item`** `ComboBox` в *PyQt5* как это сделано [здесь](https://coderoad.ru/38915001/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2-QComboBox) или [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/923693/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%8b-qcombobox-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0)
только на *Python*.

Пробовал `comboBox.setEnabled(False)`, но оно ведь просто отключает сам `ComboBox`

Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать.

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который вы уже написали и лучше расскажите что вы хотите сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Странно получается, вы несколько раз откорректировали свой вопрос,
но так и не добавили свой пример - почему?

Учитывая что это ваш первый вопрос я отвечу вам, но очень надеюсь, что в дальнейшем вы исправитесь.

Пожалуйста ознакомьтесь:

[Как задавать хорошие вопросы](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

[Вопрос — ответ. Ничего лишнего](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour).

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.combo_box = QComboBox()

        for i in range(7):
            self.combo_box.addItem("item_" + str(i + 1))  

        # QStandardItemModel, метод model.item возвращает объекты QStandardItem
        model = self.combo_box.model()    

        # Указываем какие элементы сделать невыбираемыми
        model.item(0).setEnabled(False)
        model.item(2).setEnabled(False)
        model.item(4).setEnabled(False)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.combo_box)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QFont("Times", 15, QFont.Bold))
    myapp = MyWindow()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: О, Спасибо огромное.
А на счёт примера я сначала задал вопрос а потом понял что нужно бы предоставить пример и вот только сейчас зашёл его добавлять, а тут вы)

И всё же это было легко -_- а я не додумался так же попробовать...

Спасибо ещё раз)

Comment: @DeSkree  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour